# why doesn't work registration user?

Tags: python, django, registration, django-registration

i can't registration of user work, just relog the page, someone can help me

**form.py**

```
class RegistroUserForm(forms.Form):

    username = forms.CharField(min_length=5,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    password = forms.CharField(min_length=5,widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(min_length=5,widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    def clean_username(self):
        """Comprueba que no exista un username igual en la db"""
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        if AdministracionUsuarios.objects.filter(nombre_de_usuario=username):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Nombre de usuario ya registrado.')
        return username

    def clean_email(self):
        """Comprueba que no exista un email igual en la db"""
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if AdministracionUsuarios.objects.filter(email=email):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Este E-mail ya se encuentra registrado.')
        return email

    def clean_password2(self):
        """Comprueba que password y password2 sean iguales."""
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']
        if password != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Las contraseñas no coinciden.')
        return password2
```

i use this to register a user and call in a a page HTML

**view.py**

```
def index(request):
    notifi = Notificaciones.objects.filter(user=request.user.id, Estado=False)
    usuarios = MiUsuario.objects.filter(nombre_de_usuario=request.user.id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistroUserForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # En caso de ser valido, obtenemos los datos del formulario.
            # form.cleaned_data obtiene los datos limpios y los pone en un
            # diccionario con pares clave/valor, donde clave es el nombre del campo
            # del formulario y el valor es el valor si existe.
            cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data
            username = cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = cleaned_data.get('password')
            email = cleaned_data.get('email')
            # E instanciamos un objeto User, con el username y password
            user_model = AdministracionUsuarios.objects.crear_usuario(nombre_de_usuario=username,email=email, password=password)
            # Y guardamos el objeto, esto guardara los datos en la db.
            user_model.save()
            # Ahora, creamos un objeto UserProfile, aunque no haya incluido
            # una imagen, ya quedara la referencia creada en la db.
            user_profile = MiUsuario()
            # Al campo user le asignamos el objeto user_model
            user_profile.user = user_model
            # Por ultimo, guardamos tambien el objeto UserProfile
            user_profile.save()
    else:
        # Si el mthod es GET, instanciamos un objeto RegistroUserForm vacio
        form = RegistroUserForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'notifi': notifi,
        'usuarios': usuarios
    }

    return render(request,'app/index.html',context)
```

**models.py**

```
class AdministracionUsuarios(BaseUserManager):
    def crear_usuario(self,nombre_de_usuario,nombre_completo,email,Cargo_de_Contacto,Celular,Pagina_web,Numero_de_identificacion,Nombre_de_la_empresa,Telefono,Ext,Genero,Ciudad,password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Usuario deben tener una dirección de e-mail')
        if not nombre_de_usuario:
            raise ValueError('Usuario necesita tener un nombre de usuario')
        user = self.model(
                nombre_completo=nombre_completo,
                nombre_de_usuario=nombre_de_usuario,
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                Cargo_de_Contacto=Cargo_de_Contacto,
                Celular=Celular,
                Pagina_web=Pagina_web,
                Numero_de_identificacion=Numero_de_identificacion,
                Nombre_de_la_empresa=Nombre_de_la_empresa,
                Telefono=Telefono,
                Ext=Ext,
                Genero=Genero,
                Ciudad=Ciudad,
            )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def crear_superusuario(self,nombre_de_usuario, email,telefono,password):
        user = self.crear_usuario(email,
                                  nombre_de_usuario=nombre_de_usuario,
                                  password=password,
                                  telefono=telefono,                                  
                                  )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

why is wrong with the code, because i don't find the mistake. thanks so much

Comment: @JoseRomero no, is `nombre_de_usuario`, but that line of code, i am not using

Comment: @JoseRomero pues un debug no he hecho, la verdad es que soy algo nuevo con esto, no sabría como funcionan los debug

Comment: @JoseRomero acabo de ejecutar el debug y me dice  "AdministracionsUsuarios" has no attibute 'objects'

Comment: @JoseRomero voy a editar el post

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried?

```
user_model = AdministracionUsuarios.crear_usuario(nombre_de_usuario=username,email=email, password=password)
```

Comment: i tried but now say `crear_usuario() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
`

Comment: Well, have you created a AbstractBaseUser? Because I really think it's  required when using a BaseUserManager. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser

Comment: yes, i have created, class MiUsuario(AbstractBaseUser)

Comment: ya logre solucionarlo, era decir `user_model = MiUsuario.objects.crear_usuario(nombre_de_usuario=username,email=email, password=password)`, y guardarlo, solo que ahora me dice que local variable 'form' reference before assignment

Comment: ¿Y en qué linea de código?

Comment: ya lo solucione tenia que decir que hace un `else:
form:RegistroUserForm()`

Comment: Ahora lo que sucede es que no puedo hacer el log in

Comment: no, solo me permite hacer log in con las cuentas que están en Django Administración > Autenticación y autorización > Usuarios, y con los que están creados en el model.py, no me deja hacer Log in

Comment: Revisa esto a ver si algo te falta. http://musings.tinbrain.net/blog/2014/sep/21/registration-django-easy-way/

Comment: no el registrar ya se funciona, sucede que cuando intenta hacer el Log in toma son los usuarios que vienen en la sección de Usuarios de Django Administrador, y no los del model, aunque hay forma de hacerlo, hay que cambiar el settings, para que tenga tome el user como mi model, pero cuando sucede eso se cambian muchas cosas que son para problemas

Comment: bueno ya funciona, pero no me devuelve el nombre del usuario